# How to analyse only text input in Excel or is there any software to do this?

Tags: excel, statistics, analysis

[image][image]

Building this excel file with intention of finding planets frequency position in a particular astrological house. Say Venus in how many charts Venus is posited in Virgo ? or in how many charts Jupiter is posited in Cancer. This file will be extended to more than 100 chart positions. I am not sure if this can be done in Excel is there any other software which will be helpful ?

Comment: How does your data look like? Do you have tables too or only charts? If you have a table you can use countif, Python can also be used for this purpose but it depends what you mean by charts

Comment: It is a excel file.

Comment: No charts. Data put in excel cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many times A occurs in column B, do `=COUNTIF(B:B,A)`

You should try and google before you ask a question, because most of the time the answer is already [there](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=how+to+count+cell+occurrences+in+excel+) (and it's faster)